# Content Fade In over background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this site: http://mccraymusic.com/newsite/ and I am having trouble figuring how to fade in the navigation bar correctly over the background AFTER the background has faded when clicking "enter site." I know the navigation bar isn't styled yet. I'm pretty sure I have the right code for the navigation to fade in. Just not sure how to make it work so it fades in when I want it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you just use `.delay()` method of jQuery to start the fadein later?

Comment: Can you add `position: absolute;` to your `.navbar` style? The fact that your image has `position: absolute;` is causing some z-indexing issues.

Comment: ^ This guy is right. `position: absolute` will move the `.move` container as well, try `position: relative`. I'm guessing that's the real problem in this situation

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you need to use a callback in jQuery. Basically, the second function runs AFTER the first has completed. 
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: Not actually going to down vote, but a big -1 for using w3schools. That is all. [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: fadein has a buiit in callback .fadeIn( [duration] [, callback] ) http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle of it  http://jsfiddle.net/YL4p7/

Fadein has a builtin callback, just add you animation into that callback and it will execute after the background has faded in.

also add relative position to #container so that it can be seen over the bg image.

```
$(function() {
    var images = ["black.jpg","bg.jpg"];
    $('<img>').attr({'src':'http://mccraymusic.com/newsite/assets/images/'+images[0],'id':'bg','alt':''}).appendTo('#bg-wrapper').parent().fadeIn(0);

    $('.move').animate({
            top:200,
            left:250,
    });

    $('.entersite').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image = images[1];
        $('#bg').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('#bg').attr('src', 'http://mccraymusic.com/newsite/assets/images/'+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                  $('.navbar').fadeIn(1000);
              });
        });
        $('.move').animate({"left": "-=50px", "top": "-=200px"});
    });
});​
```